# How to get image frames from video in Flutter in Windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, screenshot, flutter-desktop

In my flutter desktop application I am playing video using  [dart_vlc](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc) package. I want to take **image frames** (like screenshot) from video file of different video positions. At first I tried with [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package where I found two problems.

1. It takes screenshot of the *NativeVideo* (A widget for showing video) widget only, but not includes the image frame inside the widget.
2. And video control buttons (play, pause, volume) comes up in the screenshot which I don't want.

There's some other packages for exporting image frames from video such as [export_video_frame](https://pub.dev/packages/export_video_frame) or [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) but both of them are not supported in *Windows*. I want to do the same thing they do in Windows.

So how to get image frames from a video file playing in a video player in Windows?

Answer (score -1):

[dart_vlc](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc) package itself provides a function to take snapshots from a video file currently paying in the video player. The general structure is

```
videoPlayer.takeSnapshot(file, width, height)
```

Eaxmple:

```
videoPlayer.takeSnapshot(File('C:/snapshots/snapshot1.png'), 600, 400)
```

This function call captures the video player's current position as an image and saves it in the mentioned file.